# How can I fit my HTML page to the Web Browser in win Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I can navigate to google in a simple web browser (with doc in parent control), but i get a  resolution too bi for my component size.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you tell what you are trying to do. maybe with some pictures or some code and identify your problem there?

Comment: No more then                     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wB.Navigate(new Uri(@"https://www.google.co.il/webhp?source=search_app"));     
        }

Comment: How big is your browser control? Maybe the website is not responsive?

Comment: If i understand your question. You want to Open an Htmlpage inside an Winforms application using a WebBrowser control?

And the size of your WebBrowser control is to big even though you have docked it to its parent (Form)? Can you take a screenshot of what is happening and explain that way so we can figure something out?

Comment: Yes Jordy, this is my problem exactly!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give us a screenshot. 
I just made a new winforms-application with just the following code-behind (nothing in the designer)

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controls.Add(wb);
        wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Load += OnLoad;
    }

    private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        wb.Navigate("http://www.google.de");
    }
}
```

And everything works fine

Comment: Thank you, But I need my a small web browser componenta that here HTML page is strech for compnenta size, no application size...

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achiev.
If I understand you right, the webbrowser you have is too big for the content, right?